# Use notify.js on Angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, notify

I have a controller sending parameter to a web service, when I get the response from web service I must show a notification (that's why I use notify.js), but the code is not running. I show you:

Controller:

```
$scope.alert = function(){
        console.log($scope.q + "/" + $scope.s.id + "/" + $scope.k.id);
        // http://localhost:8080/test/cftyu/q/q/" + q + k + s
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/test/cftyu/q/q/" + q + k + s)
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
            console.log(data);
            $.notify("Hello World");
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            return data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
    console.log("fin controlador");
```

I hope anyone could help me, I know notify is called with jquery not angular I been trying to create a directive but isn't working anyway. I will appreciate any help.

Edit:
I been tryint the solution Dave Cooper proposed but it's not working:

I'm trying your solution but it's not working to me. I've got this controller:

```
app.controller('CreateQuestionsController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$window', 'sections', 'kind', 'order', 'notify',
                                       function($scope, $log, $http, 

    $window, sections, kind, order, notify) {
    $scope.alert = function(){
                return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/test/cftyu/q/q/" + q + k + s)
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    notify("Hello World");
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                });
            };
    }]);
```

Edit 2:

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pregunta</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="question"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
            <label>Clase</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-options="kind as kind.name for kind in kinds track by kind.id" ng-model="kind"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
            <label>Sección</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-options="section as section.sectionname for section in sections track by section.id" ng-model="section"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
            <button showNotify type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="alert()">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I load all the js files on the 'main' view, at the bottom like this:

```
    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controlers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controlers/CreateQuestionsController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controlers/ShowQuestionsController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/questions.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="js/directives/notify.js"></script>
```

The controller is like I posted before

Edit 3:

There is the routes and controller-view connection:

```
var app = angular.module('onBuy', ['ngRoute']); 

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/create/questions/', {
            controller: 'CreateQuestionsController',
            templateUrl: 'views/createQuestions.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use libraries supporting `angular` like https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify

Comment: I tried this library but don't know why wasn't working for me

Comment: Just try according to docs provided there

Comment: I tryed and get this error: notify.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: directive is not defined

Comment: There's a syntax error with your quotes on line 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You returned from your success and error functions before displaying your notifications, so some of your code was unreachable (i.e. you were returning your data and then trying to log things and display your notification). You can see my code below for what I mean by that.

It's probably a better idea to use an Angular service like [Angular Notify](https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify).

Here is what your code might look like with it - assuming you've injected the service into your controller (I've included a sample controller):

```
angular.module('app', ['cgNotify'])
   .controller('myController', function($scope, $http, notify) {
        $scope.alert = function(){
            return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/test/cftyu/q/q/" + q + k + s)
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    notify("Hello World");
                    return data;
                }, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                });
        };
        console.log("fin controlador");
   });
```

Hope that helps!

edit: oh you also had a syntax error in the code you provided - I fixed that up, too!

Comment: I triyed but still don't work, I changed the code but doesn't work

Comment: I triyed the link you posted but don't know why doesn't work and I don't get any message on the js console

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? If you could share your template with us, that would be good.

Comment: I share you the rest of the code, thank you very much

Comment: So there's a few things - 1. There's nowhere that's connecting your template to your controller, so nothing is getting hit, unless you've not included some other code, 2. I've changed my sample code to use `then()` instead of `success()` for your API call. If neither of those things help, then can you share any logs you have on your server to show that the request is actually hitting the server?

Comment: Sorry I missed to share the routes code, that's where I connect the view with the controller, I can see on the network tab in js console that the controller is hitting the API and also I see the form values saved in my database

Comment: Did you move to using the `then()` suggestion I provided? If so, can you confirm if the `console.log()` is getting hit at least? In your network tab, do you get a response?

Comment: I confirm I get the console.log messages and in the network tab i get response 200. Also I shared you the route code, where I connect view with the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128935/discussion-between-dave-cooper-and-proktovief).